# Duplicated saves with borgbackup

Tags: software-raid, borgbackup

I need to backup data using Borg Backup from a remote server to a local server (raspberry-pi like - it is actually Yunohost) equipped with a 2 slots storage bay. I would like to have identical copies of the backup data on each disk. Any idea how to do so? I've never done anything like this. Should I create two repositories, one on each disk, and check on Borg's settings to sync them? Or should I set a software raid 1 between both hdds?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicated saves"? Please elaborate.

Comment: Basically that I have an identical production of the save on each disk, like a "raid 1 save".

Comment: Oh, so you have two remote machines, say R1 and R2, and you want to save backups for each of these to some local machine C? And C has two disks? And for each of R1 and R2 you want copies of the data on each disk of C separately? Like a mirror? But if so, why mention your two remotes? It just complicates the question without changing it.

Comment: Right, I guess it did. Let me change the question.

Comment: I think the simplest thing to do with be to set up Linux software RAID on your two devices and then write your backups on top of that, assuming you are using a Linux-based system. And for other UNIXes there is probably something similar. I.e. leave Borg out of it.

Comment: Will do, thanks !